# Convert Content Elements field to Fluid field

Tags: upgrade, content-elements, fluid-field

I am in process of upgrading EE2 site to EE5.

One of the fields is Content Elements, and since it does not seems to be available for EE3/4/5, I'm thinking that best approach would be to convent it to Fluid field.

Has anyone went through the process before? Maybe there is some script that can be used? If not, what would be the best approach here (other than manually copy/pasting each entry)

Comment: Hey Yuri, did you have any success? Do you have any insights you can share (i.e. SQL code) ;-)

Comment: I've ended up manually copying content, as it appeared only few entries were actually using that field

Answer (score 2):

I have done this sort of migration a couple of times and it is doable but not straightforward.  Broadly you have to first get your old site to dump out the content of the field for each entry concerned in a format you can work with (i.e. some kind of structured file) and then create an appropriately capable fluid field and write some SQL to insert this information into your database using the new fluid field definition.

Because the fluid field is relatively new there are no utility add-ons available to make this process easier, and so you have to construct your approach to processing this as a custom exercise.

Whether it is worth the effort depends very much upon how many entries you are seeking to migrate... and how complex each entry is likely to be.

So, in summary, doable but non trivial.

HTH

Comment: Any recommendations for exporting the original field into "format to work with"?

Comment: It depends a bit on what you prefer when it comes to building the templates to construct the new fields, but for want of something better html_encoded CSV works OK.